# Install Samples, Binaries and Docker Images not working on mac

Tags: bash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When i follow the install doc (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/install.html) and execute

```
curl -sSL url_removed | bash -s 1.3.0
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected argument: --

Usage: bash [OPTION]... [version [ca_version [thirdparty_version]]]

OPTIONS:
    -h|--help Print this message
    -d        Bypass docker image download
    -s        Bypass fabric-samples repo clone
    -b        Bypass download of platform-specific binaries

EXAMPLES:
    To download docker images for version 1.3.0
    ==> bash -sb 1.3.0
```

Any one can help with this. I have no idea

curl --version

curl 7.62.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0) libcurl/7.62.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.11

Comment: This command runs successfully in `ubuntu18.04` but  got same error in `macOS Sierra`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue today. Fixed it using following steps:

1. Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh
2. Open the file in an editor and delete following code-block
   [image]
3. Make the file executable by running `chmod 755 bootstrap.sh`
4. Now run the file like `./bootstrap.sh`

Above is equivalent to running `curl -sSL <url> | bash`. If you want to run `curl -sSL <url> | bash -s` then edit the file and set `SAMPLES=false`

Btw running above command to install fabric would be the very first thing a newcomer to HL Fabric would try to do. If even that basic step does not work, then I have to doubt the quality of rest of HL Fabric.

Comment: i think i was just a problem using curl to get the script. we git cloned the project and installed it with the bootstrap script inside the project and it worked. But just to verify, your work around does also work